# PhantomJS crashing while running test suite

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, phantomjs

I have a rails project that has a number of Javascript tests set up to run with Jasmine through `rake spec:javascript`, yet when I try to execute the suite I get the following messages:

```
Running `"/usr/local/bin/phantomjs" "" "/Users/location/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jasmine-rails-0.12.3/lib/jasmine_rails/../assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js" "file:///Users/location/app_name/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec="`

Running: file:///Users/location/app_name/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec=

PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.

rake aborted!

Error executing command: "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs" "" "/Users/location/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jasmine-rails-0.12.3/lib/jasmine_rails/../assets/javascripts/jasmine-runner.js" "file:///Users/location/app_name/tmp/jasmine/runner.html?spec="
```

I have tried googling around for this - the issue is occurring both on TravisCI and locally. It also may be worth noting that I am unable to execute the `be rake spec:javascript` command without first prepending `RAILS_ENV=test` to the command.

So my question is this: Has anyone seen this before or have any idea why PhantomJS would consistently be crashing when the suite is executed?

These are the versions of the relevant gems I am using:

```
jasmine       - 2.4.0
jasmine-rails - 0.12.4
jasmine-core  - 2.4.1
guard-jasmine - 2.0.6
phantomjs     - 2.1.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. I think it's a bug in phantomjs 2.1.1 and jasmine. The problem can be temporarily fixed by assigning an early version of phantomjs:

```
gem 'phantomjs', '1.9.8'
```

Let me post this issue to Jasmine Rails first and see if getting any attention.

Comment: Yep...we're seeing the same thing in our project.  Our CircleCI suite (running Ubuntu 14.04 and PhantomJS 2.1.1) always hits this error.  When we revert to PhantomJS 1.9.8, the whole Jasmine suite executes fine.